# I'm trying to rig a helmet to the shoulders of the rig

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig a helmet (this particluar one is not mine, it's from an OSP). The only problem is that I want it to rig to the shoulders as well, and not just to the head.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: What? I have no idea what you just asked.

Comment: please make the title relevant to the question.

Comment: The term you need to search for is "Weight Painting": https://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/weight_paint.html